# Spring could not autowire field, No matching bean of type

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, javabeans, autowired

I try to implement using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE + Hibernate to make RESTful web service followed this guy's project https://github.com/eugenp/REST

when I run my project is contain error like this.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
*.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
*.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultUserService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
*.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.cloudlb.dao.UserDAO com.cloudlb.service.DefaultUserService.userDao;
*.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.cloudlb.dao.UserDAO]
```

This is my configuration: (persistence.properties)

ApplicationConfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cloudlb", excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)})
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        final Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[]{new ClassPathResource("persistence.properties"), new ClassPathResource("restful.properties")};
        ppc.setLocations(resources);
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }
```

In PersistenceHibernateConfig contain like this:

```
@Profile("hibernate")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceHibernateConfig { ...

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean alertsSessionFactoryBean() { ...

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() { ...

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() { ...
```

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig { ... }
```

So, it start get an error in autowired from here:

UserServiceController:

```
@Controller
public class UserServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
```

UserService which is implemented by DefaultUserService:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;
```

UserDAO:

```
public interface UserDAO extends GenericDAO<User> {  ... }
```

UserHibernateDAO:

```
@Profile("hibernate")
public class UserHibernateDAO extends GenericHibernateDAO<User> implements UserDAO{ ... }
```

GenericHibernateDAO:

```
@Profile("hibernate")
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class GenericHibernateDAO<T extends Serializable> extends AbstractHibernateDAO<T> implements GenericDAO<T> { ... }
```

And last one AbstractHibernateDAO:

```
@Transactional( propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS )
public abstract class AbstractHibernateDAO<T extends Serializable> implements DAO<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AbstractHibernateDAO() {
        super();
    }

    public final void setClazz(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional( readOnly = true )
    public T findById(String id) {
        return (T) this.getCurrentSession().get(this.clazz, id);
    }

    protected Session getCurrentSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

I thought it could find UserHibernateDAO. May be I missing something here. So, hope someone know how to fix it. I struck at this problem for 2 day.

I guess there could be a problem in SessionFactory too. Because I start to fix that thing and this came up.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have an XML file with <context:component-scan> spelling out the packages?  http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?49182-Component-Scan-Base-Package-to-multiple-paths

Comment: I'm using this: @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cloudlb", excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class)})

which is the same <context:component-scan>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `@Profile("hibernate")` the `UserHibernateDAO` needs an annotation declaring it a Spring bean like `@Named` or `@Component`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of it? So, I just put the @Component to it right?

Comment: Yes. Just put it above or beneath the Profile annotation.

Comment: When adding '@Component' and remove '@Profile' it scan see everything. After put '@Profile("hibernate")' the proplem came. Can you give me an example how to use '@Bean' to set active profile